# how to change the visual code studio commit authors

Tags: visual-studio, github, git-commit

I am not sure why, but my Visual Studio Code is showing the wrong commit author name. I am trying to change the author of the commit. How can I do that? I have already multiple things, but no luck.

[image]

This is what I tried:

Since I have three commits, I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~3`,
but I am getting this error:

> Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes. Please commit or stash them.

I am able to get to this now, how can i change the author name now?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

For the issue: `Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes. Please commit or stash them.` You can do

```
git stash // To stash the changes
git rebase -i HEAD~3 // To Rebase
git stash pop // To pop the stashed changes.
```

*Note that if the previous 3 commits include files you have stashed, you may get conflicts.*

For the *wrong commit author name*
Using your terminal `cd` into the project directory and using

```
git config user.name // Check your user name
git config user.email // Check the associated email
```

If the information is not the one you want, you can update it using

```
git config --global user.name "newemail"
git config --global user.email "newemail@example.com"
```

Note: The above will be a global change meaning that it'll change it for all `git` projects. If you prefer changing it only for the one project:

```
git config user.name "newemail"
git config user.email "newemail@example.com"
```

Comment: this does not work and does not changes commit author

Comment: @EnchantedSoul How are you testing it?

Comment: if i use stash it removes my changes. and this still gives the same error - git rebase -i HEAD~3

Comment: @EnchantedSoul After you do a `git stash` do `git status` and see if there are any files that were not stashed. The stash only stashes the tracked files. `git status` will show you the status of tracked and untracked files.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot, i was able to see the changes. what do i need to do next

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the rebase, the error message is explicit: either add and commit first, or stash.

But regarding the commit author, if you are sure the content of that commit is yours, then check your `git config user.name` / `user.email` setting: that authorship is derived from it.

Comment: this is already changed to my name but when i commit my code to github it still shows the wrong commiter name

Comment: @EnchantedSoul does it how the wring committer even for new commits that you have just done? If yes, double-check the email associated with that new commit.

Comment: @EnchantedSoul Try again, make a new commit, check locally that the commit has the right email, and push.

Comment: any instructions on that

Comment: @EnchantedSoul add, commit, push. To check locally: git log