# try to change the author name in the git commit but getting an error

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, commit, git-commit

I am trying to change the author name in the git commit but getting an error. I have tried several things but I cannot make this work.

this is what I am trying but getting the error below:

```
git commit --amend --author=“Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>”


LM0810:Automation nik.ron$ git commit --amend --author=“Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>”
bash: nik.ron@gmail.com: No such file or directory
```

I am following this tutorial - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-you-make-changes-on-a-specific-commit-779171729.html

Comment: Can you try changing it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138151/5442132 Then try doing your commit, to see if it worked, try `git log` and see the commit author

Comment: does not work i have to use the commit amend

Comment: Try -> `git commit --amend --author="Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>"` your issue might be the quotes you use for the `--author`

Comment: what do you mean? i tried the exact same thing

Comment: When using `--amend` you need `--reset-author` for Git to obey the `--author` line as given.

Comment: can you please explain the full syntax. i do not understand

Comment: @donkon What he/she means is that you have to include `--reset-author` in your command like this: `git commit --amend --author=“Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>” --reset-author`

Comment: i am getting the same error: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

To follow-up on this, I had the same issue as the poster, and as the comments suggest, the issue was indeed the quotes that I was using. From the example provided by `don kon`:

```
git commit --amend --author=“Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>”
```

Note the rounded and asymmetrical quotes around `Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>`

Replacing the `“/”` quotes with `"` quotes (see below) fixed the problem for me.

```
git commit --amend --author="Nik Ron <nik.ron@gmail.com>"
```

It would appear that the tutorial `don kon` was following ([here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-you-make-changes-on-a-specific-commit-779171729.html)) has actually been updated to use quotes that do not break the command.

Comment: Is there a typo in that - its hard to understand thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! My updated answer should hopefully be clearer :)